# CTags Jumping to Different Project

Tags: tags, ctags, plugin-easytags

I'm using CTags and the vim-easytags plugin.

I have a Python project and a C project.

In the root of the Python project, I did

```
ctags -R .
```

And all was good.  I could jump back and forth with tags in the Python project.

However, there's some keywords that exist in my other project (for instance, the variable `mode` exists in both).  If i `C-]` those tags, it opens a source file from the C project and finds that tag, erroneously.

Why is CTags getting the idea to include that project in it's searches and how do I tell ctags to only pay attention to python files for python projects and C source/header files for C projects?

Comment: I'm not sure what your directory structure looks like, but if you do `ctags -R` in a parent directory of both the C project and the Python project, both will get added. I would also try giving it an absolute path to make sure you know what you're passing it.

Comment: They're in totally different directories

Comment: One is in /media/share/python-prog and the other is in /home/user/FW

Comment: Do you have a different `tags` file for each project? If you `:chdir <project root>`, then you will use the tags file located at `<project root>/tags`. You can give us some more information about where the `tags` files are located?

Comment: There are two tags files.  One for each project.  The tags files are located in the project root directory.  I launch vim from the root directory and am using NerdTREE to move around.